# Get Errors From FactoryGirl.lint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I inherited a number of FactoryGirl factories that don't really work and I'm trying to bring them up to snuff.  Part of that has been the use of `FactoryGirl.lint`.  So far, however, I have been able to find which factories fail and, for any individual one, run

```
x = FactoryGirl.build :invalid_factory
x.valid? # returns false as expected
x.errors # prints out the validation errors for that object
```

What I'd like to do is avoid having to do that for each factory.  Is there a way to quickly get `FactoryGirl.lint` to write out the errors which each invalid factory?  A flag to pass, a parameter to set?  The documentation is extremely sparse on `.lint`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loop through `FactoryGirl.factories` to perform your check on each factory.

```
FactoryGirl.factories.map(&:name).each do |factory_name|
    describe "#{factory_name} factory" do

      # Test each factory
      it "is valid" do
        factory = FactoryGirl.build(factory_name)
        if factory.respond_to?(:valid?)
          # the lamba syntax only works with rspec 2.14 or newer;  for earlier versions, you have to call #valid? before calling the matcher, otherwise the errors will be empty
          expect(factory).to be_valid, lambda { factory.errors.full_messages.join("\n") }
        end
      end
```

---

[This script](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Testing-all-Factories-(with-RSpec)) from the FactoryGirl wiki shows how to automate the check with RSpec and use Guard to always verify factories are valid.